# Reflexive Pronouns oder Dativ

Tags: dative, reflexive

Ich kenne den Satz

> Ich mache **mir** Sorgen um dich 
>   **Mir** ist Dativ .

Aber wenn wir 'sie' benutzen 
Warum benutzen wir Reflexive Pronomen.

> Sie machen **sich** sorgen um dich

Ist es nicht **ihnen** statt **sich**  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Du scheinst deiner Frage eine unzutreffende Prämisse zugrunde zu legen.

In beiden Fällen liegt der Dativ vor, und in beiden Fällen ist das Pronomen ein Reflexivpronomen. Es gibt kein »entweder Dativ oder Reflexiv«. In beiden Sätzen liegt beides vor.

---

### Dativ

Der Dativ ist einer der vier Casus der deutschen Sprache. Es gibt:

- Nominativ. Fragewort: Wer? oder was?
- Genitiv. Fragewort: Wessen?
- Dativ. Fragewort: Wem?
- Akkusativ. Fragewort: Wen? oder Was?

Nach dem Pronomen beider Beispielsätze kann man mit »wem?« fragen:

> *Wem* mache ich Sorgen? - Ich mache *mir* Sorgen. - Dativ.
>   *Wem* machen sie Sorgen? - Sie machen *sich* Sorgen. - Dativ.

---

### Reflexiv

Beide Pronomen sind Reflexivpronomen, denn sie beziehen sich »zurück« auf das Subjekt.

Im ersten Satz ist »ich« das Subjekt, und genau auf diese Ich-Person bezieht sich das Pronomen »mir«. Daher ist »mir« ein Reflexivpronomen.

Im zweiten Satz sind »sie« das Subjekt, und genau auf diese Personengruppe bezieht sich das Pronomen »sich«. Daher ist »sich« ein Reflexivpronomen.

---

Warum nicht »ihnen«?

Der Satz

> Sie machen *ihnen* Sorgen.

würde bedeuten, dass die Personengruppe, die mit dem Subjekt »sie« bezeichnet wird, einer *anderen* Personengruppe (nämlich der, auf die das Demonstrativpronomen »ihnen« verweist) Sorgen macht. Vergleiche:

> Die Gäste freuen sich. Die Köche machen *ihnen* eine Suppe.

Hier ist die Suppe für die Gäste bestimmt. Anders in diesem Fall:

> Die Gäste sind erzürnt. Die Köche machen *sich* eine Suppe.

Hier bereiten die Köche die Suppe für die Köche, also for sich selbst zu, nicht für die Gäste.

Comment: Das hat mir alles klar gemacht :) .. Herzlich Dank . 
Ich habe nur Reflixivpronomen im Akkusativ gelernt ,
Ich habe nicht gewust , dass es auch  im Dativ gibt.

Answer (score 6):

Weil das Reflexivpronomen in der dritten Person "sich" heißt, sowohl im Dativ als auch im Akkusativ.

Beim normalen Personalpronomen gibt es in der dritten Person Plural einen Unterschied zwischen Dativ ("ihnen") und Akkusativ ("sie"), beim Reflexivpronomen nicht.

Comment: Das ist nicht meine Frage , ich denke ich habe das nicht gut eklärt.. Sich ist ein Reflexivpronome  , das verstehe ich gut . Warum haben wir kein Reflexivpronome mit dem ersten Satz benutzt , 'ich mach mich sorgen um dich '.  Ich meine warum mit einem Satz Dativ (mir) und mit dem anderen Reflexiv (sich) . Eben die beiden Satz sind gleich.

Comment: @a_barsa "Mir" ist auch ein Reflexivpronomen.

Comment: @Alex.S stimmt , aber mir für Dativ und sich für Accusative

Comment: Please read the first paragraph in the answer.

Comment: jetzt alles Klar , ich habe nur die Reflexivpronomen im Accusative genommen , ich habe nicht gewusst , dass es Reflexivpronomen für Dativ gibt . Danke sehr @Alex.S